# Why Canny output doesn't remain constant?

Tags: opencv

I am using canny edge detector with OpenCv. I am using a logitech C270 webcam. I am keeping the light conditions and all other parameters constant. Then I run canny detector in loop and displaying the output.The output of canny doesn't  remain constant. There are small variations between two consecutive output. I am curious why. Ideally shouldn't it be that canny's output remain constant if the image is constant.

Comment: The output *is* constant for constant input. There is no randomisation involved in the algorithm. Are you saying you can appy Canny to a single image multiple times and get different results?

Comment: all camera sensors are subject to quantization noise, zoom in until you can see individual pixels, you will see that they vary in slight shades from one frame to another. some cameras have noise reduction mode which operate by stacking multiple frames together(can be replicated in software if your camera fps is high enough. just get running average of last n frames). you can also try median blurring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Canny edge detector is ultimately based on one or more thresholding operations. Since all video sensors contain a certain amount of noise it is guaranteed that some of this noise will cause jitter in the Canny results.

To reduce this you should try and filter your images, e.g. with median or bilateral filters which reduce noise, so that this effect will be reduced, but it would probably never be removed completely.